# Woocommerce / ACF : add class to product <li> depending on ACF Field value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to automatically add a class to my product <li element in a grid loop, depending on ACF Field value.

I have an ACF Field that is set by the client to decide wether the product background is blue or red. I would need to get the ACF Field color info (set by hex) and add it as a class to the product <li in another page loop.
The functions below could help but I'm not sur how to make them work.

```
add_filter('post_class', function($classes, $class, $product_id) {
    if(is_product_category()) {
        //only add these classes if we're on a product category page.
        $classes = array_merge(['color-1','color-2'], $classes);
    }
    return $classes;
},10,3);
```

and

```
$fields = get_field_objects();

if( $fields ): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach( $fields as $field ): ?>

        <?php if( $field['value'] ): ?>
            <li><?php echo $field['label']; ?>: <?php echo $field['value']; ?></li>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
 endif;
```

Is there a way to integrate this in my functions.php file and make it work somehow ?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: You want to append html into class? Its unclear what u want from the code you provide...

Comment: When you say "ACF Field color info (set by hex)" - What is type of field is setup, and what are the values (just blue or red)?